# jQuery Dynamic Page Question

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following HTML page:

```
<div id="foobar">
  <?php echo $dynamicVar; ?>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="subButton"/>
```

When I press submit, the value of `$dynamicVar` will change. Is there a way, without using Ajax callbacks, .each(), or anything complicated, to do a dead-simple refresh of the div element? I know there's a jQuery function, I've seen it before, but I can't find it now. This function will just refresh an element. Everything I've found requires me to write unnecessarily complicated code to attempt to refresh a very small very simple element.

For example, if the the entire div had the value "1" inside of it, and I pressed the button, I want to refresh in order to show the value "n".

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$('#subButton').live('click',function() {
   //dead-simple element refresh, nothing fancy necessary
});
```

Example #2:

```
<div id="foobar">
   <?php echo time(); ?>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="subButton"/>
```

Since time generally goes forward, the timestamp should be different from a few seconds ago when the web server gave me the timestamp. I would want to have the div element do a very simple update of itself so that I would see the new timestamp upon button click.

Any help?

Comment: If you don't want to refresh the whole page, then AJAX is your best option.

Comment: I am using Ajax, but I don't want to have people respond that I should use an Ajax callback - in my case it is impractical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were you thinking of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load)? It's a high-level ajax function. You'd use it something like this:

```
$('#subButton').live('click',function() {
   $('#foobar').load('thispage.php #foobar > *');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use AJAX AFAIK, but in your `$.ajax()` callback, you can use `$.replaceWith()` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foobar').load('my/script.php');
```